# AngularJs: upload mutiple files from different sources

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload two different files, an image and a pdf file, each from a different input as follows:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="libraries.error.img[0] ? 'has-error' : ''">
     <label for="img">Image</label>
     <input type="file" accept="image/*" ngf-select="" ngf-multiple="true"  class="form-control" id="img" name="img" placeholder="Image" ng-model="libraries.library.img">
     <p ng-if="libraries.error.img[0]" style="color: red">{{libraries.error.img[0]}}</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="libraries.error.document[0] ? 'has-error' : ''">
     <label for="document">Document</label>
     <input type="file" accept="application/pdf" ngf-select="" class="form-control" id="document" name="document" placeholder="Document" ng-model="libraries.library.document">
     <p ng-if="libraries.error.document[0]" style="color: red">{{libraries.error.document[0]}}</p>
</div>
```

In the services file, I am sending it using the following:

```
store: function (library) {
       console.log(library);
       return  Upload.upload({
       url: 'api/libraries',
       method: 'POST',
       fields: {name: library.name, location: library.location},
       file: [library.img, library.document]
         });
       },
```

But when I try to fetch the files at the server side as follows:

```
return $_FILES;
```

I keep getting:

```
[] No Properties
```

However when I change file to

```
file: library.img
```

meaning, I pass only one file, it works.

I am using `ng-file-upload` with `AngularJS` and the server side is `Laravel`

Any idea to solve this issue allowing both files to be sent to the server?!

Comment: What browser are you on?

Comment: Multiple files should work in html5 browsers. You might need to change your server code. To verify that it is working see the network tab of your browser and request content to verify that both files are being sent to the server in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and I was able to fix it by giving the JSON object for each file a different name (drawing inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978605/using-ng-file-upload-with-rails-carrierwave-gem-to-upload-multiple-files)). If I did not rename the objects, the server would receive the correct number of files but all of them would be identical. So if you were to apply this, your code would be:

```
store: function (library) {
   console.log(library);
   return  Upload.upload({
   url: 'api/libraries',
   method: 'POST',
   fields: {name: library.name, location: library.location},
   file: [library.img, library.document]
   fileFormDataName: [name1, name2]
     });
   },
```

I believe the names can be anything as long as they are unique. However, you now have to process the objects separately on your server side. I am not familiar with how you might do that in PHP, but on my Rails back-end, I can collect all of the files by their class:

```
files = params.values.find_all { |value| value.class == ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile }
```

Then I simply assign each file to the appropriate attribute of my model.