# Using ng-file-upload with Rails carrierwave gem to upload multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, carrierwave, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to combine **ng-file-upload** and **carrierwave** to upload multiple files, but the controller on server side receives only one file (the last item of the selected files).

#### Client side ([reference](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#-usage))

**html**

```html
<button type="file" ng-model="files" ngf-select ngf-multiple="true">Upload</button>
```

**js**

```js
var upload = function (files, content) {
    return Upload.upload({
        url: 'MY_CONTROLLER_URL',
        file: files, // files is an array of multiple files
        fields: { 'MY_KEY': 'MY_CONTENT' }
    }).progress(function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('files ' + config.file.name + ' uploaded. Response: ' + data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error status: ' + status);
    });
};
```

`console.log(files)` prints *Array[File, File, ...]* (Browser: FireFox). So on client side it does get the selected files. On the **GitHub** page of **ng-file-upload** says it supports array of files for `html5`.

#### Server side ([reference](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads))

**posts_controller.rb**

```ruby
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.attaches = params[:file]
    @post.save
    render json: @post
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :file)
end
```

where `@post.attaches` is the attachments of a post and `params[:file]` is sent from client side by `file` parameter in `Upload.upload`.

I want to store an array of files into `@post.attaches`, but `params[:file]` contains only one file of the selected files.
`puts params[:file]` prints:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fddd1550300 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150812-2754-vchvln.jpg>, @original_filename="Black-Metal-Gear-Rising-Wallpaper.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Black-Metal-Gear-Rising-Wallpaper.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
```

This shows that there is only one file in `params[:file]`. I'm not sure if there is anything wrong with the usage of this parameter.

How could I solve this problem?

Here is my `post.rb` model and `attach_uploader.rb` (created by **carrierwave**) for reference if needed:

**post.rb**

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploaders :attaches, AttachUploader
end
```

**attach_uploader.rb**

```ruby
class AttachUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :file
    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
end
```

and `@post.attaches` column in database `posts` is added by

```ruby
rails g migration add_attaches_to_posts attaches:json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve my problem. Thanks for [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and [danialfarid](https://github.com/danialfarid)'s awesome [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

My problem was I couldn't send all selected files. My solution was

```js
var upload = function (files) {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i)
        names.push(files[i].name);
    return Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/v1/posts',
        file: files,
        fileFormDataName: names
    });
}
```

Then in my **rails** `controller.rb`

```ruby
file_arr = params.values.find_all { |value| value.class == ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile }

if @post.save
  unless file_arr.empty?
    file_arr.each { |attach|
      @attach = Attach.new
      @attach.filename = attach
      @attach.attachable = @post
      @attach.save
    }
  end
  render json: @post
end
```

I created an array to store all my files from `params`.

I tried to use a column with `mount_uploaders` of **carrierwave** to store an array of files, but it didn't work. So I create a file table called `attaches` to store my files

```ruby
class CreateAttaches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :attaches do |t|
      t.string :filename
      t.references :attachable, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

where `attachable` is used to store the post id and type. (Here my attachments belong to some post in my forum.)

Here is some details about setting if needed

`attach.rb` (model)

```ruby
class Attach < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :filename, AttachUploader
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

`post.rb` (model)

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attaches, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`post_serializer.rb`

```ruby
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :attaches
end
```

`attach_serializer.rb`

```ruby
class AttachSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :url, :name

  def url
    object.filename.url
  end

  def name
    object.filename_identifier
  end
end
```

Then in `html` file can have a row code

```html
<div ng-repeat="attach in post.attaches">
    <img ng-src="{{attach.url}}" type="file" height="180" width="320" accept="image/*"/>
    <a target="_self" ng-show="attach.url" href="{{attach.url}}" download="{{attach.name}}">{{attach.name}}<p></p></a>
</div>
```

where my default attachments are used for images.